# Remove HyperX RGB heatspreader and put on different HyperX DIMM?

Tags: memory, colors, rgb

Looks like HyperX doesn't have a 2x16GB RGB module set, but they do have a [2x8GB module set in RGB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CKGJPS1) (Amazon).

Question: I have HyperX DDR4 modules running at 2133Mhz at 2x16GB, could I swap the heat spreaders with this RGB kit?

This is my current kit: [HyperX Kingston Technology Fury Black 32 GB Kit 2133 MHz CL14 DIMM DDR4 Internal Memory (HX421C14FBK2/32)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D8U29CA)

Comment: I seem to recall in my research on RGB memory modules the RGB heatspreaders cannot be removed.